# Is my code in accordance with general OOD principles?

Tags: python, oop

a question relating to OOD. This is a function I have made in python for a project:

```py
def writePushPop(code, filename):
    if code[0] == "push":
        ret = pushMemory[code[1]]
    else:
        ret = popMemory[code[1]]
    
    ret = ret.replace("num", code[2])
    ret = ret.replace("filename", filename) #For static case

    if code[1] == "pointer":
        if code[2] == "0":
            ret = ret.replace("thing", "THIS")
        else:
            ret = ret.replace("thing", "THAT")
    
    return ret
```

It takes in a 'code' (it's in list form like ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']), and a string 'filename'. The given code is translated to a machine language. The function does about 4 things:

1. Determine if the code is a 'push' or 'pop' command (and get corresponding value from its dictionary)
2. Replace 'num' in abstract code to given number
3. Replace 'filename' in abstract code with actual filename (this is only to account for a single case out of 8)
4. Account for special case where code is a 'pointer'

Is this the best way to write up this code? Am not sure what's the best way to approach it, given all the design principles (abstraction, encapsulation, generalization, and decomposition) while also accounting for cohesion and coupling. Nonetheless the code seems fine to me, even though it does a few things it still relates to one thing (translating a piece of code). Bear in mind I'm not someone that works in the industry, I'm actually a university student who just started their 2nd year. I just want to gain an insight for the future for when I apply these concepts.

Comment: This may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @buran, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You could have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *is for* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.